# Why is ILogger.LogError working but not ILogger.LogInformation?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Why is it that when I inject `ILogger<MyClassName>` and call `Logger.LogInformation` I don't see that in Application Insights, but when I call `Logger.LogError` I do?

Here is my code

```cs
    public async ValueTask DeleteMessageAsync(string chatId, int messageId)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation(
            "Deleting message: {chatId} {messageId}",
            chatId,
            messageId);

        try
        {
            await TelegramBotClient.DeleteMessageAsync(chatId, messageId);
        }
        catch (ApiRequestException ex)
            when (ex.ErrorCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, "Could not Delete message");
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of the event showing up in the Live Metrics section of Application Insights.

[image: Live Metrics]

Here is the result of searching for that `InvokationId`

[image: Search]

I also get zero results when searching for the word "Piff", which is clearly in the live view.

Here is the logging section of my `host.json` file

```json
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "DurableTask.AzureStorage": "Information",
    "DurableTask.Core": "Information",
    "logLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
}
```

Here is the host builder for my Azure functions app

```cs
IHost host = new HostBuilder()
    .AddServiceDefaults(useOtlpExporter: false, isDevelopment: true)
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddSingleton<ITelegramBroadcastService, TelegramBroadcastService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationService, AuthorizationService>();
        services.AddDurableTaskClient(x =>
        {
        });
        services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
        {
            clientBuilder.AddBlobServiceClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage"));
        });
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {
        if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            config.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

The `AddServiceDefaults` extension is the one added by default in a new Aspire app.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using OpenTelemetry.Logs;
using OpenTelemetry.Metrics;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static T AddServiceDefaults<T>(this T builder, bool useOtlpExporter, bool isDevelopment)
        where T : IHostBuilder
    {
        builder.ConfigureOpenTelemetry(
            useOtlpExporter: useOtlpExporter,
            isDevelopment: isDevelopment);
        builder.AddDefaultHealthChecks();
        builder.AddServiceDiscovery();
        return builder;
    }

    public static T AddServiceDiscovery<T>(this T builder)
        where T : IHostBuilder
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddServiceDiscovery();
        });
        return builder;
    }

    public static T ConfigureHttpClientDefaults<T>(this T builder)
        where T : IHostBuilder
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.ConfigureHttpClientDefaults(http =>
            {
                // Turn on resilience by default
                http.AddStandardResilienceHandler();

                // Turn on service discovery by default
                http.UseServiceDiscovery();
            });
        });
        return builder;
    }

    public static T ConfigureOpenTelemetry<T>(this T builder, bool useOtlpExporter, bool isDevelopment)
        where T : IHostBuilder
    {
        builder.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddOpenTelemetry(telemetry =>
            {
                telemetry.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
                telemetry.IncludeScopes = true;
            });
        });

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddOpenTelemetry()
                .WithMetrics(metrics =>
                {
                    metrics.AddRuntimeInstrumentation()
                           .AddBuiltInMeters();
                })
                .WithTracing(tracing =>
                {
                    if (isDevelopment)
                    {
                        // We want to view all traces in development
                        tracing.SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler());
                    }

                    tracing.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                           .AddGrpcClientInstrumentation()
                           .AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
                });
        });

        builder.AddOpenTelemetryExporters(useOtlpExporter);

        return builder;
    }

    private static T AddOpenTelemetryExporters<T>(this T builder, bool useOtlpExporter)
        where T : IHostBuilder
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            if (useOtlpExporter)
            {
                services.Configure<OpenTelemetryLoggerOptions>(logging => logging.AddOtlpExporter());
                services.ConfigureOpenTelemetryMeterProvider(metrics => metrics.AddOtlpExporter());
                services.ConfigureOpenTelemetryTracerProvider(tracing => tracing.AddOtlpExporter());
            }

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable the Prometheus exporter (requires the OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.AspNetCore package)
            //services
            //    .AddOpenTelemetry();
            //    .WithMetrics(metrics => metrics.AddPrometheusExporter());

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable the Azure Monitor exporter (requires the Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.Exporter package)
            //services
            //    .AddOpenTelemetry()
            //    .UseAzureMonitor();
        });
         
        return builder;
    }

    public static T AddDefaultHealthChecks<T>(this T builder)
        where T : IHostBuilder
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHealthChecks()
                // Add a default liveness check to ensure app is responsive
                .AddCheck("self", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy(), ["live"]);
        });
        return builder;
    }

    public static WebApplication MapDefaultHealthCheckEndpoints(this WebApplication app)
    {
        // Uncomment the following line to enable the Prometheus endpoint (requires the OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.AspNetCore package)
        // app.MapPrometheusScrapingEndpoint();

        // All health checks must pass for app to be considered ready to accept traffic after starting
        app.MapHealthChecks("/health");

        // Only health checks tagged with the "live" tag must pass for app to be considered alive
        app.MapHealthChecks("/alive", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            Predicate = r => r.Tags.Contains("live")
        });

        return app;
    }

    private static MeterProviderBuilder AddBuiltInMeters(this MeterProviderBuilder meterProviderBuilder) =>
        meterProviderBuilder.AddMeter(
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel",
            "System.Net.Http");
}
```

Here are the app settings that are applied according to `portal.azure.com`

```json
{
    "deployment_branch": "master",
    "SCM_TRACE_LEVEL": "Verbose",
    "SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT": "60",
    "SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT": "7200",
    "SCM_BUILD_ARGS": "",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=...AccountKey=...=;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "Blob",
    "WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER_DOTNETISOLATED": "1",
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "InstrumentationKey=...IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/",
    "WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME": "Production",
    "SCM_USE_LIBGIT2SHARP_REPOSITORY": "0",
    "WEBSITE_SITE_NAME": "...",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
    "WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED": "False",
    "ScmType": "None",
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": "1",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
}
```

Comment: Are you *just* using ms logging and app insights or do you have another logging framework in there too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74364527/set-log-levels-for-microsoft-system-and-aspnet-when-using-serilog

Answer (score 1):

In your `appsettings.json` :

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
  }
},
```

If you have multiple `appsettings.json` based on your environment, be sure to select your environment properly and edit that specific `appsettings.json`.

For example, if you are in `development` environment, make sure to set these settings in `appsettings.Development.json`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it. I have updated my question with your suggested changes and added some evidence as screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

The `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()` adds a default logging rule that only allows Warning or higher to go to Application Insights.

Check the documentation here at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#start-up-and-configuration

It has a specific part that removes this default rule. Why it was implemented in the first place I don't know, but it confused me at first as well why it wasn't showing all my logs.

```
s.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
{
    // The Application Insights SDK adds a default logging filter that instructs ILogger to capture only Warning and more severe logs. Application Insights requires an explicit override.
    // Log levels can also be configured using appsettings.json. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#ilogger-logs
    LoggerFilterRule toRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
        == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

    if (toRemove is not null)
    {
        options.Rules.Remove(toRemove);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work :(

Comment: I see my answer was missing some info. If you use `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService` logging configuration no longer looks at host.json for logging setup. Please check out this github issue and specific the post linked

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1182#issuecomment-1317230604

Here he loads a json file with logging data and later on configures it to be used

Comment: I had issues where this wouldn't work. It's a matter of timing. Try using `s.PostConfigure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options => ... )` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights default value for sending information is Warning. As suggested by other answer, you could try to change the LogLevel globally, but that will be ignored by AI.

You need to explicitely configure the ApplicationInsights logging provider. Try this:

```
   "Logging":
   {
      "ApplicationInsights":
      {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning",
          "<your_namespace>": "Information"
        }
      },
      "LogLevel": {
        "<your_namespace>": "Information",
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
   },
```